# how to do composer install during docker build

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

After deploying the application to laravel, I need to run these commands.

```
docker exec -it php bash

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

exit

cd back/src

sudo chmod o+w ./storage/ -R
```

But when deploying to other developers, this is inconvenient, how can I include these commands in a dockerfile or docker-compose.yml? And even, it is possible that after build, docker-composer up -d is immediately filled

Composer does not start from the system(root), so i have to run it from another container

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why do you need to run `composer update` after deploying your application? That looks like a horrible step, as you would change the versions of your installed packages on each deployment, which makes debugging pretty difficult

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose.yml file you can set the command to update the packakges. Also set the volume, which will give the correct rights.

```yaml
php:
  command:
    - composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
  volumes:
    - ./storage/:/app/storage:rw
```

But all of this does depend on the image you're using. Which docker image do you use?

Comment: thnx for answer. i've tried your solution, but php returns 
/usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs: not found